# jQuery include form elements submit

Tags: php, jquery

Working from the ground up on a Joomla Component re-config.  I'm trying to incorporate an AJAX search function in my component.  So far, I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').submit(function() {
        var results = $('form').serialize();
        var url = 'index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&format=raw&' + results;
        $('#test').html(url);
    });
});
```

This just need to dump the values of the the form elements into a div.  right now, it will display the text string, but not the `results` var.

Comment: do you have name attributes on your inputs inside your form?

Comment: hehe.. Now it should work.. just add the name attributes the serialize will take care of the rest :)

Comment: Put that in an answer and get the cred, dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$('form').serailize()` so if your form input elements don't have any name attributes attached to them - which serialize will turn that into the key.. Then you won't get anything when you serialize the form.

Also since you are inside the form's submit function.. it would probably be better to use `$(this).serialize()` - that way if you ever have multiple forms on one page - it will know which form is getting submitted and serialize the correct form.